# How to create an https Connection in Android?

Tags: android, https

I found lots of posts in Stackoverflow but could not get the solution working for :

How to create an https Connection in Android?

Code is :

```
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(httpParameters, 25);
    int timeoutConnection = 10000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
            timeoutConnection);
    int timeoutSocket = 10000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
            .getSocketFactory(), 80));
            schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory
            .getSocketFactory(), 443));

    ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
            httpParameters, schemeRegistry);
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, httpParameters);
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code that doesn't do what you require.

Answer (score 4):

```
HttpClient httpclient = getNewHttpClient();  

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                    .getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));



            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }
```

**MySSLSocketFactory.java**

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    super(truststore);

    TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };

    sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
}

}
```

Comment: When i use this solution,it shows me "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate"

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things that you have to do when you are doing https communication with server.

1. Create a cretificate using OpenSSL tool using Bouncy Castle.
2. Load the cretificate into code and teach your code to use that.
3. Finally hit the URL to get the response using HttpResponse class

A nice example which define how it works by step by step guide is explained in this link http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/login-application-for-android-android.html#.VSE1ftyUfTB