# Do i need my private key in my mobile app to communicate to server over SSL?

Tags: android, ios, ssl, https, windows-phone

I have a paid certificate from a CA installed on my server. Do i still need to include the key in my mobile app in order to use HTTPS when communicating with my server? Or can i just add change the URL to enforce the HTTPS. Example change from http://example.com to https://example.com

Comment: By changing the URL to use HTTPS I noticed I couldn't sniff the packets using Wireshark on port 80. However on port 443, I had a hard time identifying the packets even. Does it mean the packets are encrypted and not readable?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to include the private/primary key in your app. You need to use **`SSLSocketFactor`**.

`SSLSocketFactory` example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15878972/1276495).